# Edição wiki tag de PHP

Tags: debate, wikis-de-tags

Na wiki da tag php temos como referencia um livro para iniciantes intitulado **PHP 6 e MySQL 5 para Web Sites Dinâmicos**.

Por se tratar de uma referencia bem antiga e a decisão do time interno de [pular para a versão 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/php6) (que pode ter inspirado também de certa forma a [Microsoft](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2613504/microsoft-windows/microsoft-windows-microsoft-skips-too-good-windows-9-jumps-to-windows-10.html)), acho interessante removermos essa referencia para evitar confusões.

Tentei [essa edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15675) no passado mas ela foi rejeitada. Por isso estou abrindo essa discussão.

Comment: Estava aqui a ver se me lembrava porque rejeitei, e não me consigo recordar...

Comment: @JorgeB. de novo vc na linha de fogo! hahaha.. Lendo seu motivo de rejeição, acho que você não percebeu que se tratava de uma wiki de tag, e achou que era sugestão de edição em uma publicação. Já o motivo de rejeição do brasofilo é um pouco mais difícil de decifrar.

Comment: Detalhe, tem um link quebrado lá. Quem for por a mão para editar arruma tb isso: `http://%20http//pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql`

Comment: Ahahahah estou sempre @Math. Mas eu recordo-me de falar sobre essa wiki no chat aqui. Por isso é que estou na dúvida do porque da rejeição.

Comment: Acho que esse é o [link certo](http://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2014/07/neverending-muppet-debate-of-php-6-v-php-7)

Comment: Caso ninguém se manifeste contrário posso submeter novamente minha edição mais tarde.

Comment: De fato, a não ser que eu não saiba de alguma coisa já que não conheço o livro, deveria ter sido aprovada. Parece que agora será aprovada. Acredito que o brasofilo não entendeu que o problema é o conteúdo do livro. Ou eu entendi errado :)

Comment: Devia ter pulado em vez de aprovar/reprovar. Antes de votar, fui pesquisar a questão, e lendo aquele artigo me pareceu que não devia aprovar... podia ter aberto uma meta-discussão na época... desculpas pelo mal-entendido.

Comment: @brasofilo sem problemas. Submeti novamente a edição com a correção dos links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nova edição já foi [submetida e aprovada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18553).

Answer (score 6):

A reciclagem do material de referência e manutenção da wiki são essenciais para **NÃO** disseminar conteúdo ruim/ultrapassado pois é fácil fácil tutoriais, livros, videos ensinando práticas ruins veja o uso das funções mysql_ ¬¬` por que ainda tanta gente usa? porque tem muito material e é facil de achar.

Se não me engano usuários com 4000 pontoS(beta) podem fazer edições sem precisar de aprovação. Como a sua sugestão foi rejeitada fez bem trazer ela ao meta.